# IOS MDM Push Notification Issue using Pushsharp C#

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm, pushsharp

We're working on an IOS MDM solution and we successfully enrolled a device.

Now I'm trying to Push Notification to the device using Pushsharp running on local machine but it does not reach the device and nothing is printed in the logs on Apple Device Console.
Below is how we send the notification

```
apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
{
     DeviceToken = "257c62d6336b489b78ad32b870e8d5c62a4c84bcddda2c3cbf943019XXXXXXXX",
     Payload = JObject.Parse("{\"mdm\":\"484D82B8-F8BF-4B07-B1C1-F935XXXXXXX\"}}")
});
```

The response says `Apple Notification Sent`

[image]

But nothing on the device.

Any help or any alternatives to Pushsharp which can be used in C#?

Answer (score 0):

If you did not find solution, you can try below Nuget package, I'm the author.

`Install-Package DotPush -Version 1.0.0`

Below is Github link:

https://github.com/madangehlot88/DotPush

Comment: Thanks, I do have a solution in place but I would like make use of PushSharp hence the question.But now I will certainly look into your repo :)

Comment: Hopefully you found it better. :-)